# JPopupMenuItem get component that triggered the JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, right-click, jcomponent, jpopupmenu

I have got a JRadioButton and set a ComponentPopupMenu to it.

```
JRadioButton rdbtnTest = new JRadioButton();
rdbtnTest.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

The popupMenu is a `JPopupMenu` with one `JPopupMenuItem`. The `JPopupMenuItem` has a `MouseListener`, so that on a mouse click, a webpage is opened.

```
JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu("GO");
PopupMenuListener popupMenuListener = new MyPopupMenuListener();
popupMenu.addPopupMenuListener(popupMenuListener);
MenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open Webpage");

openMenuItem.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Component comp = arg0.getComponent(); // will only return the JPopupMenuItem
            // Determine the right-clicked radio button and open webpage
        }
popupMenu.add(openMenuItem);
```

My question is: if I have another `JRadioButton rdbtnTest2` with the same popupMenu, can I determine which of the two radio buttons triggered the JPopupMenu? When opening the webpage, I need to pass a specific parameter according to which radio button was right-clicked.

Comment: +1 for using `setComponentPopupMenu()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whn you show popup menu in a MouseListener just get event source and store it somewhere (radiobutton which calls the menu). In your code just check the popup invoker.